# hosting dashboard app in shinyapps.io failing to start with code 1

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, host, shinyapps

I have created a shiny dashboard and it is working fine on `http://127.0.0.1:4829/`. However,
the button to publish to shinyapps.io has disappeared in Rstudio. Also, when I try to upload just my `app.R` file to shinyapps.io, I get the message:

An error has occurred
The application failed to start (exited with code 1).

```
Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    box


Attaching package: ‘DT’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:shiny’:

    dataTableOutput, renderDataTable


Attaching package: ‘shinyjs’

The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:

    runExample

The following objects are masked from ‘package:methods’:

    removeClass, show


Attaching package: ‘shinyWidgets’

The following object is masked from ‘package:shinyjs’:

    alert

Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Can't call `runApp()` from within `runApp()`. If your application code contains `runApp()`, please remove it.
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Comment: search in your code, you should only have 1 instance of `runApp()`, you error is saying you have 2 `runApp`s in your code. resetting your R session might also help as it clears variables and stuff during your last session.

Answer (score 0):

using `deployApp()` instead of `shinyApp()`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26954537)

Comment: I was the author and it does clarify. I have corrected my code just changing it.